# How to import dict initialized in init constructor from one python file to another?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to import my dictionary in a python file to another dictionary. When I try:

filename1.py

```
from filename import myDict
```

I get "ImportError: cannot import name myDict" and I imagine this is because my dictionary is initialized as follows:

filename.py

```
def __init__(self):
    self.myDict = {}
```

I have also tried:

filename1.py

```
from filename import self.myDict
```

And then I get a syntax error that says the "." in self.myDict is invalid. If anyone can provide any suggestions on how to resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `__init__` is for classes, not modules.  I think you can just use a normal variable.

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear in my post before but my __init__ is part of a class I created!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dictionary isn't actually part of a class, take it out of `__init__` and just declare it:

```
myDict = {}
```

Then, you can just import it as you had:

```
from filename import myDict
# Now use myDict as if it was declared in this file
print myDict
```

If it is in a class, then import the class:

```
from filename import className
```

Then use the dict via the class:

```
print className().myDict # or do something else with it
```

Comment: however when I print my dictionary, I only have keys:values that I added in to the dictionary in the `__init__` function....there are other functions in the original file/class that add keys:values to the dictionary which are all called in my main() function

is there anything I can do to make sure all my keys/values are in my imported dictionary? thanks so much again!

Comment: That's because you are instantiating a new version of the class when you call `classname().myDict`. If you want those functions to have been called, you'll have to import the whole file (or still just the class if all of the functions are within it) and call them manually.

Comment: You can also make another function within the class that calls the functions that you want and returns the dictionary, then create a new object of the class in filename1.py, like `newClassObject = className()` and then call the new function to return the dictionary into a new dictionary object: `newDict = newClassObject.callFunctions()`. Or something like that. Let me know if that makes sense/you need more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

filename.py

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myDict = {}
```

filename1.py

```
from filename import X
print X().myDict
```

Comment: sorry about that I'm new to stackoverflow! need at least 15 points before my upvote shows up